# Getting 404 response code on Azure Cognitive services api

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, azure-cognitive-services

Here's a tricky problem I am facing.

I have an http-triggered azure function. I have a Microsoft cognitive services api endpoint. It is accessible through the url I have. It works with postman and returns the expected results.

But when I use call the cognitive services api from my laptop, it gives me a 404.

Here's what I verified so far.

1. Ensured that url is correct. I copied the url from the debugger and tested it in postman, just to rule out configuration errors.
2. I upgraded my azure functions runtime to the latest version, just to rule out any azure cli/functions runtime issues.
3. Upgraded my visual studio and all azure related plugins

The final culprit I am investigating is that I am using WebResponse which is deprecated and I should be using HttpClient instead.

404 response codes are the easiest thing I have had to debug in my whole career. Never had a problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the client code to user System.Net.HttpClient from System.Net.WebResponse and everything works. Very strange, but there you go. The cognitive api client does not like what it's receiving from the http client when I use WebResponse.

For those who'll run into this bug. This happened when I upgraded Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions from 1.0.9 to 1.0.13.